# What is the flat dimension of $I(R)$ for $R$ the free algebra in $n$ variables?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra

Let $R$ be the free non-commutative algebra in $n$ variables and let $I(R)$ be the injective envelope of the regular module $R$.

> Question 1: Is $I(R)$ flat?

> Question 2: More generally, let $R=KQ$ be the quiver algebra of a quiver with finitely many points that may contain cycles. When is $I(R)$ flat?

When $Q$ is acyclic, this can happen only when $Q$ is a linear oriented line.

Comment: Have you looked at Colby, "Rings which have flat injective modules" J Algebra 35 (1975), 239-252?